# Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 18 to the 15 allowed

Tags: java

I am getting sonar warning to reduce its complexity. How can I refactor the below code to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 18 to the 15 allowed?

```
@Override
   
        
        try {
            Field[] members = MSAUnderlyingStrategyDTO.class.getDeclaredFields();
            Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.model.MSAUnderlyingStrategyDTO");
            for (Field m : members) {
                if (!m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("serialVersionUID")
                        && !m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("DATE_FORMAT")) {
                    var audit = new Audit();
                    audit.setAuditType("ADD");
                    audit.setClientId(1);
                    audit.setEntityId(msaStrategy.getStrategyId());
                    audit.setCreatedBy(user);
                    audit.setCreatedOn(new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    audit.setEntityName(MSASTRATEGY);
                    audit.setAttributeFromValue(null);
                    Object obj = c.getDeclaredMethod(createMethodName(m.getName())).invoke(msaStrategy);
                    if(obj!=null&& !obj.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        audit.setAttributeToValue(obj.toString());
                        if(m.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("msaUnderlyingStrategyName"))
                            audit.setAttributeName("underlying_strategy_name");
                        else
```

Comment: keep a map where you map the names to the attributenames, that 'll save you about ... 5 ifs already. But SO isn't really a "code review" group. There are better places to post this

Comment: And just saying: maybe you should avoid copy/pasting your companies production code to stackoverflow. Remember [mcve]. Especially those hardcoded package names that give away your company ... consider editing that out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Simple: by moving content into helper methods.

The real point here is: code quality doesn't come out of tools. It needs the developers to have a **common understanding** how good code *should* look like.

Which requires: for developers to spend time learning and thinking about it.

Long story short: start by reading a good book, like "Clean Code" by Robert C. Martin. That book for example suggests that you always only have a single level of abstraction in your methods. One way to get there: by a lot of small helper methods. Your code has **4**: try - for - if - if. Theoretically, each *body* (try / for / if / if) could go into its own method.

Meaning: you can reduce the complexity of that one method by moving the complicated checks in different places. Alternatives, you also could restructure the code completely. As user [Stultuske](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2636929/stultuske) suggests: in the end, your code is doing some sort of **mapping**. Those one solution would be to use a map, and that knows to map `strategyId` to `strategy_id`. (and note: many libraries doing so DTO mapping actually have built in strategies for reworking names from `camelCase` to `snake_case` for example. You are (sort of) re-inventing the wheel here.

Comment: That helped me get more knowledge, thank you

Answer (score 0):

One simple step for these kinds of issues is to check the for loop.

Could probably extract the contents of the for loop to a method.

```
  for (Field m : members) {
      Audit a = createAudit(arrlist, m);
      if(a!=null) arrlist.add(audit);
  }
```

Comment: Note: this is already introducing another smell: the code by the OP doesn't result in null Audit objects. So: if that `createAudit()` method fails for one reason or the other, then it should probably throw an exception. But returning null to indicate error is **bad practice**. Don't do that, don't advise other people to do it like that. Returning null is your first step towards running into NPEs. Just dont do it.